# a variation on Hanson-Wright inequality

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, measure-concentration

The classic Hanson-Wright inequality states that for a Gaussian random vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I})$ and $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\big|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]\big|>t\bigg\}\le 2 e^{-c\min\left(\frac{t^2}{||\mathbf{A}||_F^2},\frac{t}{\|\mathbf{A}\|}\right)}
\end{align*}
Now assume $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ (I'm ok with assuming $m\le n$). Also assume $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Then I'm interested in upper bounding the following failure probability
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\big|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}f(\mathbf{x})-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}f(\mathbf{x})]\big|>t\bigg\}\le ???
\end{align*}
Obviously this depends on assumptions on $f$. I'm particularly interested in the case where the entries of $f$ are lipschitz that is
\begin{align*}
|f_i(\mathbf{x})-f_i(\mathbf{y})|\le L||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||_{\ell_2}\quad\text{for}\quad i=1,2,\ldots,m
\end{align*}
In general I'm interested in the case where

$f(\mathbf{x})=g(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x})$ where $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ aplies the same nonlinear function to each entry of its input. That is

$f_i(\mathbf{x})=\phi(<\mathbf{B}_i,\mathbf{x}>)$ where $\phi:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is a nonlinear function. I would like to make minimal assumptions about $\phi$ e.g. Lipschitzness or boundedness.

Comment: Is $f$ bounded?  What are its growth properties?  At least linear?  Without this detail, it seems that this question does not uniquely identify a problem.

Comment: I'm interested in linear type of growth properties (please note the Lipschitz assumption)

Comment: The Lipschitz assumption does not imply that $f$ has linear type growth; take, e.g., $f(x) = \cos(x)$.

Comment: I do not want too assume too much about the functions but let me give two specific examples that I'm in particular interested

Comment: Thanks, yes you are correct. I do not want too assume too much about the functions but let me give two specific examples that I'm in particular interested in. f(x)=sign(Bx) where B is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and sign is applied to each entry. Another example is f(x)=phi(Bx) where and $phi:R\rightarrow R$ applies entrywise and $\phi(x)$ is 0 when $x<0$ and $\phi(x)=x$ for positive x. I'm in general interested in f(x)=phi(B*x) and would like not too make too many assumptions on phi but Lipschitzness/bounded ness I think would be a good starting point.